# Chart.js isn't rendering data correctly

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a mongo query that I'm using to render data on the front end. When I tried using it, it was returning [object Object] on the front end but I fixed it using JSON.stringify.

The problem is that now that I've got the data correctly (I guess), it isn't rendering.

I have the following code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('chartAt').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: [],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Gráfico de atendimento',
                    <% for(var i=0; i<testatm.length; i++) { %>
                    data: [<%= JSON.stringify(testatm[i].sum) %>], // parâmetros do banco
                    <% } %>
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgb(71, 87, 112)',
                        'rgb(229, 226, 27)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgb(71, 87, 112)',
                        'rgb(229, 226, 27)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

What I'm getting on the sources tab from the google dev console is this:

label: 'Gráfico de atendimento',

```
                data: [5], // parâmetros do banco

                data: [17], // parâmetros do banco

                data: [35], // parâmetros do banco

                data: [65], // parâmetros do banco

                and it goes on...
```

But the chart I get is a big one with the number 2 on it, which is weird.

Hope I can get some help, thanks!

Comment: An object cannot have duplicates keys (like `data` in your case). `data` has to be an array containing all data points.

Comment: Any tips on how could I do it?

Comment: I don't know your "backend", but as it looks like it uses JavaScript... remove the loop and use `data: [<%= testatm.map(function(t) { return t.sum }).join() %>]` instead